# Multiple forms in a MVC pages (routing)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET MVC.
I have a page with 2 forms, the current page is: http://localhost/Puzzles/5754

```
<form action="/Puzzles/5754/Solve" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="solution" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form action="/Puzzles/5754/write" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My current routing is

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Puzzles",
            "Puzzles/{puzzleId}",
            new { controller = "Puzzles", action = "Details" }
        );
```

How do I handle the submit?
I want the two form to go to the same View.
I'm willing to change the approach.

If you want context: The page shows a riddle, the user can submit a solution or write text asking for help.
There will be more forms, like rating\bookmark\ect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this routing (default action is Details)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Puzzles",
    "Puzzles/{puzzleId}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Puzzles", action = "Details" }
);
```

and in returning View of both controller actions (Solve, Write) add name of view

```
return View("your-view", model);
```

Comment: That was simpler than I thought it would be!